# A-frame not picking up a cubemap

Tags: aframe

I am trying to create a simple animation of falling dices. With below code, I am trying to apply a cubemap to a-box but not able get the desired results.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.2.0/aframe.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <a-scene>
            <a-assets>
               <a-cubemap id="sky">
                    <img src="dice/Dice-1.png">
                    <img src="dice/Dice-2.png">
                    <img src="dice/Dice-3.png">
                    <img src="dice/Dice-4.png">
                    <img src="dice/Dice-5.png">
                    <img src="dice/Dice-6.png">
               </a-cubemap>
            </a-assets>   
            <a-entity geometry="primitive: box" material="envMap: #sky"></a-entity>
          </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, environmental maps, using i.e. cubemaps, are used to provide a sphere environment, or work with reflecion/refraction, by providing a map of the surrounding environment.

In Your case, I would use a texture for `<a-box>`, or create a custom box made of planes, and texture them accordingly like this:

```
<a-entity id="dice">
     <a-plane position="-0.5 0 0" rotation="0 -90 0"></a-plane>
     <a-plane position="0.5 0 0" rotation="0 90 0"></a-plane>
     <a-plane position="0 0.5 0" rotation="-90 0 0"></a-plane>
     <a-plane position="0 -0.5 0" rotation="90 0 0"></a-plane>
     <a-plane position="0 0 0.5" rotation="0 0 -90"></a-plane>
     <a-plane position="0 0 -0.5" rotation="0 0 90"></a-plane>

   </a-entity>
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x8dt1jjb/.

Cubemaps:
As I see from multiple sources, cubemaps had many issues:
Like [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/804) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555449/aframe-envmap-not-applying-to-first-primitive)

I found some guy claiming that cubemaps work on all entities except the first one, check out his [github](https://github.com/scottmsinger/aframe/tree/master/tests/env_map_order),
cubemaps are working on his [index.html](https://cdn.rawgit.com/scottmsinger/aframe/109c9427/tests/env_map_order/index.html)

Please note, indeed cubemaps on his example are not working on the first entity, so my advice would be copying his cubemap declarations, and create `<a-entity>` with your envMap applied, but with scale="0 0 0", or visible="false". When made so, the first entity get's 'bugged' (but invisible, so who cares), and Your entity should work fine.

 Works properly for me, inverted my sources though: http://gftruj.nazwa.pl/cubemap/
Note, that there is an order in which You need to declare faces of Your cubemap, as explained [here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/material.html#standard). Looking at a [dice cubemap](https://usercontent2.hubstatic.com/4764316_f520.jpg), you need to get your order straight, for example:
dice-5, dice-2, dice-4, dice-3, dice-6, dice-1

btw I found a [cubemap component](https://github.com/bryik/aframe-cubemap-component), didn't tried it yet though.

Comment: I have tried it out. However, it does not wrap the texture of dice faces successfully around dice like one dot one one side and on the opposite side six dots.

Comment: @PrakashBayas check out my update, I think You need to reorder Your faces in the cubemap

Comment: I tried cubemap from the given link, the dice showed only three faces namely, bottom, left and back. Also, component cubemap does not go hand in hand with dynamic-body component. I, also, was not able to load the inspector with this node server up for any of the examples given in that github repository. I updated the order as well with no fruitful result. After my research along these lines, I conclude that the work for a perfect cubemap texture around a-box or similar entity is still in progress.

Comment: Hi Piotr, the below code worked for a dice

    <a-entity id="dice">
         <a-plane position="-0.5 0 0" rotation="0 -90 0"></a-plane>
         <a-plane position="0.5 0 0" rotation="0 90 0"></a-plane>
         <a-plane position="0 0.5 0" rotation="-90 0 0"></a-plane>
         <a-plane position="0 -0.5 0" rotation="90 0 0"></a-plane>
         <a-plane position="0 0 0.5" rotation="0 0 -90"></a-plane>
         <a-plane position="0 0 -0.5" rotation="0 180 90"></a-plane>
    
       </a-entity>

I needed to add 180 degrees in the last plane to make it a perfect cube.